# Use access token provided by firebase Facebook auth to access Facebook API?

Tags: firebase, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using firebase integrated facebook login, which authenticates the user and provides an access token. If I want to leverage the Facebook API further can I pass the access token into the javascript sdk? There doesn't appear to be a way to do this in the documentation.

If not, how can I make an HTTP Call to facebook API, what I am trying results in a 400 bad request OAuthException

```
        var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/userId';

        var data = {
            client_id: myAppId,
            access_token: accessTokenFromFirebaseFacebookAuth
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(data, status) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data, e1, e2) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1. Use `signInWithPopup` to sign in with Facebook and get the Facebook access token and then query the Facebook API:

`AJAX GET 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + result.credential.accessToken`

Firebase also returns additional data:
`firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {...`

Check content of `result.additionalUserInfo.profile`

2. Sign in with Facebook web SDK. Get the Facebook access token and then sign in to Firebase:
   `firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookAccessToken)).then(function(result) {...`

If you need to continuously use the Facebook API, use option 2 as Firebase does not manage OAuth tokens after they expire.
If you just need Facebook data on sign-in, then use option 1.